# Laravel 8 date timezone not changing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, timezone

i've been stuck on an issue which i'm passing a date in a request from Vue to a Controller, the date data in Vue is correct but when i pass it to the controller the date is wrong.
I changed the timezone in app.php to "Europe/Athens", cleared cache and views but still nothing.

```
Vue Date Data: Thu Oct 08 2020 19:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) 

Controller Request Date Data: 2020-10-08T16:00:00.588Z
```

The date data in controller is always 3 hours behind.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: that means your backend have info in `UTC` so there should not be a problem.

Comment: **toArray** or **toJson** method on Eloquent models are always expressed in **UTC**, with **ISO-8601** format.

Comment: Actually the title is completely wrong, the timezone is changing, but it has no effect on this particular data.

Comment: So, shall i use carbon to make it work? @sta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i used date format and passed the date request with strtotime function.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(request('date')));
```

And it worked like a charm.